# sizeof and function template: sizeof(&f) vs sizeof(&f<int>)

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, clang, language-lawyer

As mentioned by [[5.3.3/3]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.sizeof#3) (*expr.sizeof*, working draft):

> The sizeof operator can be applied to a pointer to a function, but shall not be applied directly to a function.

The following minimal, working example compiles fine:

```
void f() { }

int main() {
    sizeof(&f);
}
```

I would expect that also the one below would work:

```
template<typename T>
void f() { }

int main() {
    sizeof(&f<int>);
}
```

Anyway, even if it compiles with clang (v3.8), it does not using GCC (v6.1).
The error is:

> error: address of overloaded function with no contextual type information

I suspect it's a bug of GCC (I will open a ticket if confirmed).
Am I right or I'm missing something here and GCC is right indeed?

---

Meanwhile, I opened [an issue](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=77474) to GCC.

Comment: It's a bug.3210

Comment: @Columbo is 3210 the bug ref or an amarcord mention of the Nokia mobile phone? :-)

Comment: It's me being annoyed by the ludicrous minimum comment length. ;D

Comment: @Columbo Ahahah... Touché. The best reason indeed!! Sorry for the stupid question, it was so obvious. ;-)

Comment: @Columbo Do you know whether that bug is already reported?

Comment: @DanielJour I've just reported it anyway... Didn't find the bug, but I'm not the best with the search engine on bugzilla.

Comment: @skypjack Can you add a link to your bug report here?

Comment: @melpomene Right. Did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug. The following code compiles fine:

```
template<typename T>
void f() { }

int main() {
    auto fptr = &f<int>;
    return sizeof(fptr);
}
```

---

Note that at first I didn't read the question attentively. I was under the impression that the function `f<int>` is indeed overloaded, for example as below:

```
template<typename T>
void f() { }

template<typename T>
void f(T) { }

int main() {
    sizeof(&f<int>);
}
```

Under such reading of the question I prepared the following answer, which I still want to share with the community:

---

I wouldn't qualify it as a bug.

The argument for qualifying it as a bug is the following - all function pointers have the same size, so why does it matter which function is meant inside the `sizeof` operator?

I am going to defeat that argument.

First of all, it starts from the wrong premise. The C++ standard only guarantees that

> converting a prvalue of type “pointer to `T1`” to the type “pointer to
>   `T2`” (where `T1` and `T2` are function types) and back to its original type yields the original pointer value

which doesn't necessarily mean that the size of pointers to functions of different types is the same. I admit, however, that in practice this is true.

Next, even if we accept the premise and logic behind the argument, then we must also accept the claim that the following program should also compile without any problem:

```
template<typename T>
void f() { }

template<typename T>
void f(T) { }

int main() {
    auto fptr = &f<int>;
    return sizeof(fptr);
    // fptr is not used anywhere else, so the compiler must not
    // whine about the ambiguity on its declaration line
}
```

Continuing in this manner, we would argue that compilation ambiguities should never be reported provided that they are eliminated by subsequent code.

Comment: The same bug is present in MSVC: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Valid-sizeoff-results-in-compilation/1548361